# Finding a list based on the outcome of another list

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, list

I have a document upload system where the user can add `Distributees`. These people have access to view these documents. I am having difficulty showing these shared files to the distributees.
Currently it finds the user logged in, finds the distributees shared (The distributees model has the user and id saved into it) then using this it searches for the documents with the found distributees (`myshared`).

However I get the error `"Operator "==" cannot be applied to the type of int and list"`

```
// GET: DocumentUps
public ActionResult DocumentsShared()
{
    string currentUser = this.User.Identity.GetUserName();

    var myshared = db.Distributees.Where(a => a.UserIdSaved == currentUser).ToList();

    var mydocs = db.DocumentUps.Where(a => a.DocumentId == myshared).ToList();


    return View(mydocs);
}
```

What im trying to do is'

> find distributees for logged in user
>
> find documents related to distributees

Comment: Since you gave us 0 information about your tables, data and what you've tried all I can say is - appears to be a MySQL subquery. Good luck.

Comment: As per the error, you are attempting to compare an integer with a list: `a.DocumentId == myshared`. You cannot do this. It makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a simple join between distributees and documentUps.

Or something like this:

```
var myshared = db.Distributees.Where(a => a.UserIdSaved == currentUser).Select(x => x.DocId);

var mydocs = db.DocumentUps.Where(a => myshared.Contains(a.DocumentId)).ToList();
```